# iPhone UILabel not updating on first load

Tags: iphone, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` that does not update on first load but does load correctly on every other subsequent load.

Here is the snippet of code. Again, as I said, on the first load only it will display what's specified in the label in the xib, i.e `label`, and the second time it will load the string `label.text= @"Glass, Paper, Cans, Textiles, Card, Shoes and Books";`.

```
-(IBAction)showDetails:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Annotation Click");
    self.userProfileVC.title=((UIButton*)sender).currentTitle;
    if([((UIButton*)sender).currentTitle isEqualToString:@"Asda"])
        self.userProfileVC.label.text= @"Glass, Paper, Cans, Textiles, Card, Shoes and Books";

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Curl Page Down" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown 
                       forView:self.view cache:YES];    

    //Adjust the Subview by butting up to status bar
    self.userProfileVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    //Add userProfileVC as a subview
    [self.view addSubview:userProfileVC.view];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that at the time you access `self.userProfileVC.label` at the first time, the `label` is still `nil` because the view itself hasn't been loaded yet. The quick fix is that you must load the view first by putting `self.userProfileVC.view;` statement at the beginning of the `showDetails` method.

Comment: Thanks mate you gave me the clue I just moved the view to load first!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this code is called when you click your UIButton. So at first UI load I wouldn't expect your method to get called (as no button was pressed). Why don't you try setting up the default text in `viewDidLoad` or similar?

e.g. something along the lines of:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.userProfileVC.label.text= @"Glass, Paper, Cans, Textiles, Card, Shoes and Books";
}
```

Comment: Great that has loaded whats above into the label but now the information is the same for all the annotations? I have 52 if statements that have different information how would i go about fixing this :-)

Comment: "all of the annotations" - no idea what you mean, as I can't see what you're doing and you've never mentioned annotation before. If you mean that you have lots of 'if isEqualToString:@"Asda"' type stuff, consider storing the label->annotation mapping in an NSMutableDictionary (or plain NSDictionary). Then you can lookup the annotation via the label text without having a huge load of 'if's.

Answer (score 0):

I am such an idiot I have changed the order of my code....load the view first before the labels. DOH!

Heres the snippet:

-(IBAction)showDetails:(id)sender{

```
//Must load the view before the annotations update the label with the correct label text!
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Curl Page Down" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown 
                       forView:self.view cache:YES];    

//Adjust the Subview by butting up to status bar
self.userProfileVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
//Add userProfileVC as a subview
[self.view addSubview:userProfileVC.view];
[UIView commitAnimations];

NSLog(@"Annotation Click");
self.userProfileVC.title=((UIButton*)sender).currentTitle;
if([((UIButton*)sender).currentTitle isEqualToString:@"Asda"])
    self.userProfileVC.label.text= @"Glass, Paper, Cans, Textiles, Card, Shoes and Books";
```

Comment: You probably meant to accept tia's answer rather than post your own. If you wanted to give a clarification on how you finally got it fixed, you could edit your question and include a "solution part" at the end.